# Java Fx, Edit the textarea of a specific tab

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, tabpanel

Well, my question is simple.
I am building an application with Java Fx, and I have a TabPane. 
When I open a new Tab, that Tab gets it's content by a fxml file. 
`tab.setContent((Node)FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("/main/textEditor.fxml")))`

Fine, that works well, it always loads the same file on all Tabs, so, all textarea on all tabs have the same id. 
The problem is, with java, I can only get the information of the textarea of the first Tab.

 How can i edit specifically the textarea of one tab in particular?

An example of what i want to do :

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application{


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Application.launch(Main.class, args);
     }

     @Override   
     public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {  
         Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/tabPane/test.fxml"));


         Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
         Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

         stage.setScene(new Scene(root));



         stage.show();
     }
}
```

**test.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tabPane.controller">
   <children>
      <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
         <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="File">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="insert" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Insert" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
         </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="155.0" layoutY="177.0" style="&#10;" text="Drag components from Library here…" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#9f9f9f" wrapText="false">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="640.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
               <tabs>
                  <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
                     <content>
                        <TextArea fx:id="textarea" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="a" />
                     </content>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
                     <content>
                        <TextArea fx:id="textarea1" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="a" />
                     </content>
                  </Tab>
               </tabs>
            </TabPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@../../../../BasicApplicatio11n_css/BasicApplication.css" />
```

**controller.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TextArea textarea;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {


    }
    public void test(ActionEvent event){

        textarea.appendText("Text");

    }

}
```

There are two tabs on this example, when the button is pressed, I want to add the text on the current selected tab.

Comment: "The problem is, with Java, I can only get the information of the textarea of the first tab". I'm not sure what this means. Can you post some code to clarify what the issue is? Does your `textEditor.fxml` file have a controller? If so, each controller instance will reference the nodes in the corresponding ui, so that is the place to do any logic.

Comment: It has a controller, and that button is linked to the method above, the problem is that the only thing that changes is the textarea of the first tab, and not the current one.

Comment: The button is part of the textEditor.fxml file?

Comment: Same file, but outside the TabPane.

Comment: how can it be outside the tab pane? The elements defined in textEditor.fxml are all placed in the tab as its content. Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: That doesn't look much like what you described, but let me try to answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this. One way is to let the controller for the tab content expose the `textProperty` from the text area. Then in your "main controller", create a `StringProperty` field. When you create a new tab, just observe its `selected` property and update the string property field to point to the one from the current controller. Then you can easily load text into the "current" pane.

Here's a simple example of this:

EditorController:

```
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class EditorController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea ;


    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return textArea.textProperty() ;
    }
}
```

with textEditor.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="EditorController">
    <center>
        <TextArea fx:id="textArea"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

And then the MainController could look like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane ;

    private StringProperty currentText ;

    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        // load an initial tab:
        newTab();
    }

    @FXML
    private void newTab() throws IOException {
        Tab tab = new Tab("Untitled text");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textEditor.fxml"));

        tab.setContent(loader.load());

        EditorController controller = loader.getController() ;

        tab.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (isNowSelected) {
                currentText = controller.textProperty();
            }
        });

        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
    }

    @FXML
    private void load() {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(tabPane.getScene().getWindow());
        if (file != null) {
            Path path = file.toPath();
            try {
                currentText.set(String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(path)));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setContentText("Unable to load file "+path);
                alert.setTitle("Load error");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
            tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setText(path.getFileName().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

with main.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController">
    <center>
        <TabPane fx:id="tabPane"/>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="5">
            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" right="5" left="5" bottom="5" />
            </padding>
            <Button text="Load..." onAction="#load" />
            <Button text="New" onAction="#newTab"/>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

For completeness, a simple application class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There are other approaches, e.g. you could just change the button's `onAction` property when the tab selection changes, etc.

Comment: I adapted pieces of that code to my program and it works like a charm. Awesome, thanks.